For a charged hollow sphere: why is the energy calculated from the electric field different to its total energy?
I'll first calculate from its electric field, the energy of a charged hollow sphere of radius R carrying charge $Q$. I'll then show that this is different to calculating the total energy directly from constructing the charged sphere from its components at infinity.
From electrostatics, the electric energy density is given by $$U = \frac{\epsilon}{2}E^2.$$ Integrating this over the volume outside the charged sphere, the inside electric field being zero, gives the energy:
$$U = \int^{\infty}_{R}\frac{\epsilon}{2}\left(\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon r^2}\right)^24\pi r^2dr = \frac{Q^2}{8\pi\epsilon R}.$$
For the second calculation, the work done in compressing the charged sphere from a radius of $\infty$ to $R$:
$$U = \int^{\infty}_{R}\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon r^2}Qdr = \frac{Q^2}{4\pi\epsilon R}.$$
I'm under the impression that both methods should give the same total energy of the charged sphere, yet the first is half that of the last: why?

Why do you expect those energies to be equal?

@md2perpe in standard texts on CED since Poynting that I've read, the total energy of an EM system is the sum of the energy of the current densities and that of the EM field for the continuous charge model which I'm presenting.

The electric field experienced by the surface charge is not $Q/4\pi\epsilon_0r^2$. That's the electric field just outside of the surface. The electric field inside the surface is zero. So what electric field do we use?
Well we can consider this in detail:

I'll "regulate" the problem by introducing some finite width in your hollow sphere $w$. The electric field a distance $x$ through the charged surface is $E_0x/w$, where $E_0=Q/4\pi\epsilon_0r^2=\sigma/\epsilon_0$, where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density. Then if I want to move the entire slice to the right by a distance $\delta$, the work per surface area is:
$$
\int_0^w \frac{\sigma E_0x\delta}{w^2}dx=\delta\sigma E_0/2
$$
So you see that it is equivalent to declare that the slab as a whole is experiencing an electric field of $E_0/2$, not $E_0$. This brings the two answers into agreement.
The broader lesson is that since the electric field is discontinuous at a surface charge, the effective electric field experienced by the surface charge is the average of the electric field on both sides.
